# ERROR 0 - Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

[image: SP Page builder pro 3.8 version Facing error in frontend editor of homepage only.]

The code where the error occurs is:

```
$css .= 'height:'.$gallery_height.'px;';
$css = '';
if($gallery_height){
    $css .= $addon_id .' .sppb-gallery-parallax:after {';
    $css .= 'height:'.$gallery_height.'px;';
    $css .= '}';

    $css .= '@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {';

    $css .= $addon_id .' .sppb-gallery-parallax:after {';
    $css .= 'height:'.$gallery_height_sm.'px;';
    $css .= '}';

    $css .= '}';

    $css .= '@media (max-width: 767px) {';

    $css .= $addon_id .' .sppb-gallery-parallax:after {';
    $css .= 'height:'.$gallery_height_xs.'px;';
    $css .= '}';

    $css .= '}';
}
return $css;
```

Comment: Thank for joining us Shakeel.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback/support.  Can you please `var_export()` all of the variables in your script? I don't know which of those variables is the object.

Comment: The error occurs in a 3rd party template. Have you updated your template to the latest version? And what's line 67 in your script?

Answer (score 2):

The first line is trying to concatenate a string onto the end of `$css`, but `$css` would have to already be a string (or be a variable type that can be cast to a string, like an integer) for that to work. If it's an object then that would cause your error. We'd need to see how and where `$css` gets generated in the first place.

The second line is sticking out for me.

```
$css = '';
```

It completely overrides the line before it and makes it pointless, as well as any earlier references to `$css` that aren't included in the code above. I would point this out to the template developers in case it has been left in by error.